# How to get heroku to use environmental config for DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, postman, mlab

Heroku identifies in logs that it is trying to reach out to a MongoDB shard I am not using (but used once). The error message says:

> "failed to connect to server
>   [swarmage-shard-00-00-ekq8j.gcp.mongodb.net:27017]"

but I have no idea why it is trying to connect to that server.

I am deploying a `node.js` app to `heroku`.  Heroku is linked to my `MLAB` database. 
 I can, via the mongo shell, interact with the database.  When I run on a local server, postman can do all CRUD operations on the MLAB database.  However, when I use the heroku webaddress in postman, I get a 503 error.  The log shows a "`MongoNetworkError`" and a "`TransientTransactionError`".  But the main issue, I think, is that it is trying to reach out to a Cloud Atlas shard that I am no longer running.  I have no connection strings in my code; they are all set by environmental variables.  I have updated and double checked that both my local system is set to the new connection strings and that `heroku` is configured for the new connection strings.  I have no idea where `heroku` (or mlab? or mongodb?) is grabbing the old connection shard from.

I have tried unset configs for both `heroku` and the local server.  I have tried to find the old instance of the shard on `cluster atlas`, but can't.  Everything works until I try to use postman to reach out to the heroku address.

I can't find anything in the heroku docs or mongo saying anything about doing more than clicking on the connection strings and putting them in the code.  I also tried putting the correct connection strings directly into the code--no change.

I figure there is a default setting somewhere that I need to change, but I have no idea where.

I don't think the code will help, but for sake of showing code (it's all up on [Github](https://github.com/TGetschman/voter-backend))

**production config:**

```
{
  "name": "SwarmAge - Production",
  "mail": {
    "host": "prod-mail-server"
  },
  "title": "Welcome to the Swarm Age"

}
```

**custom-environmental-variables**

```
{
  "mail": {
    "password": "SwarmAge_password"
  },
  "jwtPrivateKey": "SwarmAge_jwtPrivateKey",
  "connectionString": "SwarmAge_db"
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const winston = require("winston");

require("./startup/logging")();
require("./startup/routes")(app);
require("./startup/db")();
require("./startup/config")();
require("./startup/validation")();
require("./startup/prod")(app);
require("./startup/status")(app);

app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", "./views");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () =>
  winston.info(`Listening on port ${port}`)
);

module.exports = server;
```

**start up config**

```
const config = require("config");

module.exports = function() {
  if (!config.get("jwtPrivateKey")) {
    throw new Error("FATAL ERROR: jwtPrivateKey is not defined.");
  }
};
```

**start up db**

```
module.exports = function() {
  const db = config.get("connectionString");
  mongoose
    .connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false
    })
    .then(() => winston.info(`Connected to ${db} . . .`));
};
```

from the terminal, 
heroku configs (to go to Heroku, where is it getting the shard from?):-------

```
C:\Users\tedgo\voter>heroku config
```

swarmage-backend-190625 Config Vars

```
NODE_ENV: production
SwarmAge_db: mongodb://AdminGLOC:fakopassword@ds155461.mlab.com:55461/heroku_6qxb8b19
SwarmAge_jwtPrivateKey: hidden
SwarmAge_password: not-important
jwtPrivateKey: took-this-out-as-well
```

my settings (to go to Cluster Atlas--this works)

```
SwarmAge_db=mongodb+srv://AdminGLOC:not-my-real-password@swarmage-0idyv.gcp.mongodb.net/development?retryWrites=true
```

And here is the error message from the logs:

> cat uncaughtExceptions.log
>   {"error":{"name":"MongoNetworkError","errorLabels":["TransientTransactionError"]},"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException:
>   failed to connect to server
>   [swarmage-shard-00-00-ekq8j.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect
>   [MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.]\nMongoNetworkError:
>   failed to connect to server
>   [swarmage-shard-00-00-ekq8j.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect
>   [MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.]\n    at Pool.
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:431:11)\n
>   at Pool.emit (events.js:189:13)\n    at connect
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:557:14)\n
>   at callback
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:109:5)\n
>   at provider.auth.err
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:352:21)\n
>   at _authenticateSingleConnection
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\auth_provider.js:66:11)\n
>   at sendAuthCommand
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:215:18)\n
>   at Connection.messageHandler
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:334:5)\n
>   at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)\n    at processMessage
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:364:10)\n
>   at TLSSocket.
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:533:15)\n
>   at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)\n    at addChunk
>   (_stream_readable.js:284:12)\n    at readableAddChunk
>   (_stream_readable.js:265:11)\n    at TLSSocket.Readable.push
>   (_stream_readable.js:220:10)\n    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread]
>   (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)","stack":"MongoNetworkError:
>   failed to connect to server
>   [swarmage-shard-00-00-ekq8j.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect
>   [MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.]\n    at Pool.
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:431:11)\n
>   at Pool.emit (events.js:189:13)\n    at connect
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:557:14)\n
>   at callback
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:109:5)\n
>   at provider.auth.err
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:352:21)\n
>   at _authenticateSingleConnection
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\auth_provider.js:66:11)\n
>   at sendAuthCommand
>   (C:\Users\tedgo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\sc

Comment: When you say you have removed the config on Heroku do you mean from `project->settings->Config vars`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer comes from coder Santiago Beltram.
-several issues.
--First, the default.config file needed to hold all variables found in custom-environmental-variable.  It did not.
--Second, in models.supporters.js there was an error where "require('jsonwebtoken')" was written in camel case "require('jasonWebToken')".  This would not require the proper program.
--Third, not all dependencies appeared in the package.json file.  As such heroku did not know to include them.
After fixing the code and including the missing dependencies in package.json by using a --save flag, the program was successfully deployed to heroku.